# Wordpress copy of Google Sites

Tags: wordpress, tree, navigation, sidebar, google-sites

I have a google site https://sites.google.com/site/shahriarinia/ and I want to build its equivalent in wordpress. Features are:

1. Have 100+ pages in website that are organized in a *hierarchical* manner.
2. Have a side bar navigation of the whole website in **tree form** (this is the ONLY reason I loved google sites)
3. be able to attach a file to a page (This is not too critical but if possible that's highly appreciated.)

To all WP gurus: how can I do this? which plugins/themes shall I use? I don't care if I have a blog there, having a blog is the least priority. I am the only user of the site, so there is no roles or other users using stuff.

Something like [CMS Tree Page View](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/) but not for admin purposes but for the actual site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hierarchical manner , you can build a bar navigation. Look your Option Menu and look " Manage Sites"
If you want to attach File on a page , look your "Option Menu" or press "m"  and look page Settings  and Allow attachments.

For you bar Navigation , Menu option and " edit site layour".